# use gulp to rebase CSS urls

Tags: css, sass, npm, gulp

I have a question about how to solve the following situation:

In my sass-files I use absolute path variables in my main include files, e.g. fonts are located in /assets/fonts/... and icons are located in /assets/icons/... and so on. Now these paths are obviously working only when the domain is in root.

The environment I wish my application to run on has a different  folder structure which goes a few levels deep.

Here is an example of the file structure in my development environment:

```
/root
    assets
        icons
        ...
    home
        home.scss
    page1
        module
            module.scss
```

Here is an example of the file structure in the new environment:

```
/root
    various
        subfolders
            assets
                icons
                ...
            css
                home
                    home.css
                page1
                    module
                        module.css
```

As can be seen: The compiled CSS gets created in subfolders which can become quite deep, i.e. like 8 stories deep. The root declaration in my css will no longer work because of the new tree structure.

My options are as follows:

- adjust my sass so that at all paths are relative (don't like to do that, will make my sass more complicated, everything seems to be good the way it is)
- adjust my .htaccess so that this is covered (don't like that either, have to adjust everytime I switch the environment, seems "hacky")
- create/use a gulp task that fixes my compiled css files so that the relative paths are added to all findings of `url("/assets`

I have searched quite a lot, looked into thread2, gulp-tap and gulp-replace. But somehow I can't quite get it right. For instance: The obvious solution, gulp-replace, is not working as I need it to because I need to get information about the file that is currently in the pipe (to get its file.path and thus find out how many stories the file has climb up to reach the assets folder).

Does anyone has ever done this? Or maybe has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, solved it myself. I have created a gulp-plugin for this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-adjust-url-path